# How does the browser cache assets, and how does it know when they are stale?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm just curious as to how the browser caches things like javascript, sylesheets, etc.  In a lot of cases I see redirects when fetching these things, so how does the browser know that a particular thing is stale?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: [How long does Google Chrome cache a resource if expires and/or no-cache headers are not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740822/how-long-does-google-chrome-cache-a-resource-if-expires-and-or-no-cache-headers)

Comment: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/